# SIMD - _mm_set_epi32 - установка значений наоборот

Tags: c++, c, simd

Извините, подскажите пожалуйста, почему или зачем в функции _mm_set_epi32 установки значений - сделана установка, как бы в обратном порядке ?

> __m128i _mm_set_epi32 (int e3, int e2, int e1, int e0)
>
> Устанавливает упакованные 32-битные целые числа в dst с
> предоставленными значениями.

```
Operation:
dst[31:0] := e0
dst[63:32] := e1
dst[95:64] := e2
dst[127:96] := e3
```

То есть как видно из описания, если я сделаю:

```
__m128i my_m128i =  _mm_set_epi32 (0, 1, 2, 3);
```

Значения занесутся в вектор, как бы не слева на право, как обычно это делается при инициализации к примеру массива, а наоборот с права на лево.

Зачем такая "путаница" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нумерация битов идет с конца, то есть если представить последовательность бит как массив то нулевой индекс в данном случае будет равен 127.

И получается что e3 записывается в старшие биты со 127 по 96, а e0 в младшие с 31 по 0.

То есть такой порядок обусловлен тем, что именно в нем будут храниться значения.

Comment: Но функция _mm_set_epi32 - записывает указанные значения группой 4 байта, я же указываю значения не бит, а группы бай. Биты могут записываться с конца, но зачем байты записываются с конца ?

Comment: Байты состоят из бит, если вы посмотрите как будет выглядеть 4-х байтовое число 5 в битовом виде то это будет
`00000000000000000000000000000101`.